# Nested Subscriptions with RxJava Timers and Timeouts

Tags: java, asynchronous, timeout, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Using RxJava2, I am trying to accomplish some timed events.

I have a few async events that might complete in less than one second, and I want to be displaying a message to the user for at least one second, before continuing on with the result of the async operation (and maybe use that result later).

The async operation may also timeout, and I would want to display a message and not continue.

I can accomplish this by using an `zip()` with the timer as the first parameter and the async operation as the second operator, but what do I do with the next 'layer'?

This is the code I have so far, which actually ***does work***, but I feel very dirty creating nested subscriptions (using `just()` in place of the async operation, and ignoring subscription threads)

mStrings is just a `BehaviorSubject<String>`.

```
mStrings.onNext("Waiting 1 second. The result will fire at the Single.timer onComplete");
Single.zip(Single.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), Single.just("First"), (t1, t2) -> t2)
  .timeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS, observer -> {
      mStrings.onNext("First timeout fired");
  })
  .subscribe(s1 -> {
      mStrings.onNext("First timer fired and returned " + s1);
      Single.zip(Single.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), Single.just("Second"), (t1, t2) -> t2)
        .timeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS, observer -> {
            mStrings.onNext("Second timeout fired");
        })
        .subscribe(s2 -> {
            mStrings.onNext("Second timer fired and returned " + s2 + ". Previous was " + s1);
            Single.zip(Single.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), Single.just("Third"), (t1, t2) -> t2)
              .timeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS, observer -> {
                  mStrings.onNext("Third timeout fired");
              })
              .subscribe(s3 -> {
                  mStrings.onNext("Third timer fired and returned " + s3 + ". Previous was " + s1 + " and " + s2 );
              });
        });
  });
```

The result of which is:

```
17:53:53.219 Waiting 1 second. The result will fire at the Single.timer onComplete
17:53:54.220 First timer fired and returned First
17:53:55.224 Second timer fired and returned Second. Previous was First
17:53:56.224 Third timer fired and returned Third. Previous was First and Second
```

Am I missing an operator that would make sense in this type of flow? Or some elementary methodology? I know I might be able to work out an alternative solution using multiple subjects, but it seems excessive.

Comment: so you want to fire some async operation each 1 second, and to display a status message each 1 sec, that prints all previous async op result? what if asycn result returns after 1 sec?

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed my own issue. `flatMap` can be used to condense all the subscriptions into one, and each individual `timer` and `timeout` will still operate as expected.

```
mStrings.onNext("Waiting 1 second. The result will fire at the Single.timer onComplete");
Single.zip(Single.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), Single.just("First"), (t1, t2) -> t2)
  .timeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS, observer -> {
      mStrings.onNext("First timeout fired");
  })
  .flatMap(s1 -> {
      mStrings.onNext("First timer fired and returned " + s1);
      return Single.zip(Single.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), Single.just("Second"), (t1, t2) -> t2)
        .timeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS, observer -> {
            mStrings.onNext("Second timeout fired");
        })
        .flatMap(s2 -> {
            mStrings.onNext("Second timer fired and returned " + s2 + ". Previous was " + s1);
            return Single.zip(Single.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), Single.just("Third"), (t1, t2) -> t2)
              .timeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS, observer -> {
                  mStrings.onNext("Third timeout fired");
              })
              .flatMap(s3 -> {
                  mStrings.onNext("Third timer fired and returned " + s3 + ". Previous was " + s1 + " and " + s2 );
                  return Single.just("Fourth");
              });
        });
  })
  .subscribe(s -> {
      // ignored
  });
}));
```

The complex nesting can still be simplified by composing the Observables a bit more logically.